# Does writing to '/dev/null' or 'NUL' affect the hard drive?

Tags: linux, windows

I read `/dev/null` is a special file that "throws away" everything written to it, but does writing directly to it use the hdd in any way? Or how about the RAM?

For example:

```
wget http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip -o /dev/null
```

Similarly for Windows, does writing to `NUL` also behave the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing to `/dev/null` does not affect the HDD in any way. The same is true for Windows `NUL`.

One thing that *is* different is that `NUL` is a "special" name, whereas `/dev/null` is not.

When you use `/dev/null` on Linux (or any Unix), the OS goes and looks for the file with that name. If it does *not* find one then it will create an actual real file called `/dev/null` and write the data to disk; this can happen if you forgot to mount the `/dev` filesystem, or something.

If `/dev/null` does exist, as it should, then the OS will detect that it is a character device file, with magic numbers 1 and 3 (major and minor), and the special driver for writing to that device kicks in ..... and discards your data without reading it.

You can actually create your own `null` file, anywhere you like (and call it whatever you like):

```
sudo mknod --mode=666 my_null c 1 3
```

and then this will work too:

```
echo "dump this!" > ./my_null
```

I don't know why you would though? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/null` is not like traditional files.

The `/dev/` directory is a mountpoint for the *devfs* (Device Filesystem) pseudo-filesystem. Using the form of a filesystem *devfs* acts as a device manager that displays each device as a file.

This pseudo/virtual filesystem is not on the hard-drive. It is in **memory**.

The files in `/dev` are generated by the kernel to provide software and processes access to devices.

The file `null` that is in the `/dev/` directory has no size, its creation date is the same as the system's boot-up time and has read and write permissions for all users.